# Echo'ing php as "return value" to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

My **jquery** code:

```
    var value = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "to_submit.php",
            data: $('#submit').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            async: true
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log("data received");
            console.log(response.data);
            $("#appended").append(response);});
        }).error(function() {});
        });
```

and **PHP**

```
include("../header.php");
$to_return = "test";
echo "\ndata: " . json_encode($to_return);
flush();
```

How the console.logs in the javascript part behaves:

> first console.log:  (a lot of **code information** (head, body, etc) related to my website header!)
>
> still first console.log: data: "test"
>
> console.log("data received");
>
> second console.log: undefined

So, data is being recognized as ***undefined*** and a lot of code is being flushed, and I can't figure out why...

Comment: Why exactly are you including your `header.php` in the script you call with ajax? Not surprising that stuff related to your website header comes up...

Comment: @jeroen my php script was misnamed. You pointed me towards that so http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l8w2ymyt161qbjt25o1_500.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: first, you shouldn't need to use `flush()` - simply `echo` your data and end your script.

Second, the results of your `echo` statement: `data: ["insert your data here"]` is not valid JSON and you're not going to be able to decode it on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
echo "\ndata: " . json_encode($to_return);
```

To

```
echo json_encode($to_return);
```

Cause this string can't be parsed properly by js decoding function (it is not a valid json string).